# virtual function in inhertiance hierarchy

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

When I have something like this, and when I have `a* mya=new c();` and I call `a->displayStuff` it calls `Class a` method, and when `virtual` is in `Class a` instead of `Class b`, it calls `Class b` method.

Since `Class c` has no implementation of this method, what is the rule applied here?

```
class a
{
public:
void displayStuff() {}
//other methods
};

class b:public a
{
public:
virtual void displayStuff() {}
//other methods
};

class c:public b
{
//other methods
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It just creates confusion for anyone wanting to use your class hierarchy. Remember, you should write code with the assumption that an axe-wielding maniac will end up supporting it..!

Comment: I have an examination and oh believe me our professor is going to ask us something like this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first your case class A has no virtual function. So its non-virtual function displayStuff will be called. in the second case when you added function specifier virtual to the function in class A the corresponding function inclass B redefines this function. So in the second case the function of class B is called because the table of virtual function pointers contains a pointer to the function defined in class B.

Comment: You mean that in the first case, my object is going to search for the first non-virtual function? and the second case, my object will look up to the "nearest" base class to use its method?

Comment: In both cases the compiler searches a function with name displayStuff in class a. As in the first case it is not virtual then it is called because it is found in class a. In the second case when you added function specifier virtual the compiler also finds the function. But as it is virtual the compiler access the table of pointers of virtual functions where the address of the class b function is written. So it calls the function of class b.

Comment: That it would be simpler imagine that each object that have virtual functions contains a pointer to the table of pointers of virtual functions. As class c did not override the virtual function of class b then the contents of the table is the same as for class b.

Comment: I find it best to just try out the code myself, so I quickly implimented it, and it matches what Vlad says.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mxRQjZgfe9qirOUjCqjSufo5M1ApXzNX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sample is for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

> Since Class c has no implementation of this method, what is the rule
>   applied here?

The rule of inheritance applies. Based on the visibility of the inherited member and the inheritance type, the members visible in Class B would be visible in Class C. In this case, as you are inheriting publicly, all public members would be visible publicly. So, the public virtual member function in Class B would be visible as a public virtual function in Class C.

> Exactly, but when to use what and why when I have multiple levels of
>   inheritance?

Its a design decision. Remember, a non virtual member function is bound at compile time, so any Function Call via a base pointer cannot be resolved until you intend to call the function.
Consider the scenario

```
                                        Base
                                      public: foo
                                       /    \
                                      /      \
                                     /        \
                                    /          \ 
                                   /            \
                                Derived1      Derived2    
                              public: foo   public: foo

Base *p;
std::cin>>cond;
if (cond)
    p = new Derived1();
else
    p = new Derived1();
p->foo();
```

In the above code, the decision to call foo() (Derived1::foo or Derived2::foo), depends on some external condition which cannot be determined at runtime. The only way to make this possible is create a vTable which can only be forced to be created if we make at-least one function in a class virtual (Note any virtual function in the base class continues to remain virtual in the derived class).

Comment: Exactly, but when to use what and why when I have multiple levels of inheritance?